# Migrating Spark InLine If view syntax to Razor

Tags: razor, syntax, spark-view-engine

We have a ton of spark views I'm migrating over to Razor and in many places we use the inline spark if syntax as shown below.

```
<viewdata about="AboutViewModel" />

<div class="button-container" if="about.shouldShowButton">
    <button class="about-acknowledge" type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a nice compact similar razor syntax.  But all I've been able to come up with is this.

```
@if(ViewData["about.shouldShowButton"].Equals(true)){
    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="about-acknowledge" type="button">Click Me</button>
    </div>
}
```

While individually that's not terrible, when you have a few of them close together and they are nested in other tags it gets pretty nasty real fast.

**EDIT**

I've made my view into a strongly typed view and that has cleaned it up a little but I would still like something a little more compact if possible.

```
@model Project.Models.AboutViewModel
@if(Model.ShouldShowButton){
    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="about-acknowledge" type="button">Click Me</button>
    </div>
}
```